# action creator does not return value to stream in marble test

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I've got following Epic which works well in application, but I can't get my marble test working. I am calling action creator in `map` and it does return correct object into stream, but in the test I am getting empty stream back.

```
export const updateRemoteFieldEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(UPDATE_REMOTE_FIELD),
    filter(({ payload: { update = true } }) => update),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
      const { orderId, fields } = payload;
      const requiredFieldIds = [4, 12]; //  4 = Name, 12 = Client-lookup
      const requestData = {
        id: orderId,
        customFields: fields
          .map(field => {
            return (!field.value && !requiredFieldIds.includes(field.id)) ||
              field.value
              ? field
              : null;
          })
          .filter(Boolean)
      };

      if (requestData.customFields.length > 0) {
        return from(axios.post(`/customfields/${orderId}`, requestData)).pipe(
          map(() => queueAlert("Draft Saved")),
          catchError(err => {
            const errorMessage =
              err.response &&
              err.response.data &&
              err.response.data.validationResult
                ? err.response.data.validationResult[0]
                : undefined;
            return of(queueAlert(errorMessage));
          })
        );
      }
      return of();
    })
  );
```

On successfull response from server I am calling `queueAlert` action creator.

```
export const queueAlert = (
  message,
  position = {
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "center"
  }
) => ({
  type: QUEUE_ALERT,
  payload: {
    key: uniqueId(),
    open: true,
    message,
    position
  }
});
```

and here is my test case

```
describe("updateRemoteFieldEpic", () => {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  let scheduler;
  beforeEach(() => {
    scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  it("should return success message", () => {
    scheduler.run(ts => {
      const inputM = "--a--";
      const outputM = "--b--";
      const values = {
        a: updateRemoteField({
          orderId: 1,
          fields: [{ value: "test string", id: 20 }],
          update: true
        }),
        b: queueAlert("Draft Saved")
      };

      const source = ActionsObservable.from(ts.cold(inputM, values));
      const actual = updateRemoteFieldEpic(source);

      const axiosStub = sandbox
        .stub(axios, "post")
        .returns([]);

      ts.expectObservable(actual).toBe(outputM, values);
      ts.flush();
      expect(axiosStub.called).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

output stream in `actual` returns empty array
I tried to return from map observable of the action creator which crashed application because action expected object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By stubbing `axios.post(...)` as `[]`, you get `from([])` in the epic - an empty observable that doesn't emit any values. That's why your `mergeMap` is never called. You can fix this by using a single-element array as stubbed value instead, e.g. `[null]` or `[{}]`.

---

*The below is an answer to a previous version of the question. I kept it for reference, and because I think the content is useful for those who attempt to mock promise-returning functions in epic tests.*

I think your problem is the `from(axios.post(...))` in your epic. Axios returns a promise, and the RxJS `TestScheduler` has no way of making that synchronous, so `expectObservable` will not work as intended.

The way I usually address this is to create a simple wrapper module that does Promise-to-Observable conversion. In your case, it could look like this:

```
// api.js

import axios from 'axios';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function post(path, data) {
  return from(axios.post(path, options));
}
```

Once you have this wrapper, you can mock the function to return a constant `Observable`, taking promises completely out of the picture. If you do this with Jest, you can mock the module directly:

```
import * as api from '../api.js';

jest.mock('../api.js');

// In the test:
api.post.mockReturnValue(of(/* the response */));
```

Otherwise, you can also use redux-observable's [dependency injection mechanism](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html)  to inject the API module. Your epic would then receive it as third argument:

```
export const updateRemoteFieldEpic = (action$, state, { api }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(UPDATE_REMOTE_FIELD),
    filter(({ payload: { update = true } }) => update),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
       // ...
       return api.post(...).pipe(...);
    })
  );
```

In your test, you would then just passed a mocked `api` object.

Comment: Yes, the promise in the text is result of trial and error in my testing, previsously I was going around that by mocking axios and returning empty array, which is acceptable return for rxjs and since I care just about success or error, it should work correctly, I have similar structure working in other tests, just in this one I can't get any result in the stream, I'll update the code with original code.

Comment: with updated code it works synchronously and TestScheduler shouldn't have problem.

Comment: @iamwtk, if you let `axios.post` return `[]`, you end up with `from([])` - an empty stream. Your map function will not be called because there is no element to process. Try stubbing with a one-element element like `[null]` or `[{}]`.